# passwd Authentication token error CENTOS 7

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I'm traversing through a list, and with each iteration I'm creating a user/password using the following command:

```
useradd -c "$first $mi $last" "$uname", "$pw" | passwd "$uname" --stdin
```

every time i run this command, for each iteration it tells me, changing password for user... then it says, passwd Authentication token error.

thanks

Comment: Just use `useradd ... -p "$pw"`

Comment: this didnt work for me? i dont think i used the command propery..

Comment: useradd -c "$first $mi $last" $uname -p "$pw"

Comment: It should work with `useradd -c "$first $mi $last" -p "$pw" "$uname"` and you usually want to add `-m` to create the home directory, e.g.  `useradd -m -c "$first $mi $last" -p "$pw" "$uname"`. You can also specify the users `UID` with `-u` and `GID` with `-g`. See `man usersdd` for the details.